# Is it possible to insert data into two different tables inside one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this tables which names are

> > Users table

and

> > Pictures Table

whose primary job is to store the picture path and name and user id(Am doing it this way because I want to allow the users of my app to upload more than a picture which if I create a column for the picture in the users table will not allow me to do that).

Now inside the form(Signup form), if a user decide to upload a picture, I want the picture to be save inside the pictures table while still in the

> > Users_controller create method

This is what I have done so far (new.html.erb)

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
          <%= render'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :username %>
          <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

          <span class="picture">
            <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
          </span>
          <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and inside the users controller, I have this in the create method

```
1. def create
2.  @user = User.new(user_params) # Not the final implementation!
3.
4.  if @user.save
5.      # Save to the picture name to the picture table
6.               if params[:picture].present?
7.                 # How do I save the picture to the picture table from users controller
8.            @user.send_activation_email
9.        flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
10.       redirect_to root_url
11. else
12.     #@states = State.all
13.         render 'new'
14. end
15.  end
```

If you look at line 6 and 7, I have these

```
if params[:picture].present?
  # How do I save the picture to the picture table from users controller
```

That is where the problem is now, how do I insert the picture name into the database inside user_controller

Comment: Short answer is yes, you can do this, and it doesn't look very different no matter _what_ controller you're calling it from. There is no firm rule that you must _only_ create records of a single type in a controller. I can make an answer, but first, a question - are you using paperclip to handle your uploads? Or some other gem?

Comment: I'd suggest using [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @maxpleaner no, I use mini-magick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# new action
def new 
  @user = User.new
  @user.pictures.build
end

# create action
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, pictures_attributes: [:id]) 
# in addition to the id you need to specify the other required fields.
end
```

```
# User model
class User
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```
# form view

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  pictures:
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture_form| %>
    # your code
```

Sometimes in `f.fields_for :pictures`, you need to write `:pictures_attributes` by hand, if the first option does not work for you:

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures_attributes do |picture_form| %>
```

and write field names by hands:

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures_attributes do |picture_form| %>
  <%= picture_form.text_field :name, name: "user[pictures_attributes][][name]" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is nested forms.
Nested forms accepts params of a child class also and in the view you can add as many images as you want and it will get stored in its respective table. 
Check out - https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form